# Find the start of the index of a phrase in a list

Tags: python, list

Assuming I have this list:

```
text = ['Malte', 'ex', 'precio', 'empcionis', 'bovum', 'septem',  'laborancium', 'et', 'unius', 'thaurj', 'et', 'unius', 'vacce', 'cum', 'vitulo', 'sequenti', 'et', 'pecudum', 'fetancium', 'sexdecim', 'et', 'duarum', 'caprarum', 'cum', 'duobus', 'et', 'cum', 'vitulo']
```

And I want to find every index of the beginning of 'cum vitulo' ie: 13 and 26.

At the moment I am getting the start of 'cum' but sometimes this is followed by another word ex: 'duobus' in this case

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Also, why would you expect 26 and not 23

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
text = ['Malte', 'ex', 'precio', 'empcionis', 'bovum', 'septem',  'laborancium', 'et', 'unius', 'thaurj', 'et', 'unius', 'vacce', 'cum', 'vitulo', 'sequenti', 'et', 'pecudum', 'fetancium', 'sexdecim', 'et', 'duarum', 'caprarum', 'cum', 'duobus', 'et', 'cum', 'vitulo']

target = 'cum vitulo'
target = tuple(target.split())
hits = [i for i, x in enumerate(zip(text, text[1:])) if x == target]
print(hits)  # -> [13, 26]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way IMHO (python 2.7 and 3):

```
text = ['Malte', 'ex', 'precio', 'empcionis', 'bovum', 'septem',  'laborancium', 'et', 'unius', 'thaurj', 'et', 'unius', 'vacce', 'cum', 'vitulo', 'sequenti', 'et', 'pecudum', 'fetancium', 'sexdecim', 'et', 'duarum', 'caprarum', 'cum', 'duobus', 'et', 'cum', 'vitulo'];

result = [i for i, item in enumerate(text[:-1]) if item == 'cum' and text[i+1] == 'vitulo']
print(result)  # >>> [13, 26]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
text = ['Malte', 'ex', 'precio', 'empcionis', 'bovum', 'septem',  'laborancium', 'et', 'unius', 'thaurj', 'et', 'unius', 'vacce', 'cum', 'vitulo', 'sequenti', 'et', 'pecudum', 'fetancium', 'sexdecim', 'et', 'duarum', 'caprarum', 'cum', 'duobus', 'et', 'cum', 'vitulo']

result = []
for index, value in enumerate(text):
    if value == 'cum':
        try:
             if text[index + 1] == 'vitulo':
                 result.append(index)
        except IndexError:  # reached end
            break
```

output

```
result == [13, 26]
```

---

A fancy way:

```
from itertools import tee

# recipe from itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


[index for (index, (first, second)) in enumerate(pairwise(text)) if first == 'cum' and second == 'vitulo']
```

Comment: not the downvoter, but for your first snippet, you could simply loop over `text[:-1]`. Finding `'cum'` in the last position would be a guaranteed no-match anyway. So you can also drop the `try-except`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes but that copies the list which should be avoided. `itertools.islice` would be better but is a bit of extra explanation.